# Simple Bash Script Error and Advice - Saving Environment Variables in Linux

Tags: bash, heroku-toolbelt

I am working on a project that is hosted in `Heroku`. The app is hard coded to use Amazon S3 and looks for the keys in environment variables. This is what I wrote after looking at some examples and I am not sure why its not working.

```
echo $1
if [ $1 != "unset" ]; then
        echo "set"
        export AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXX
        export AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        export S3_BUCKET_NAME=XXXXXXXXX
else
        echo "unset"
        export AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''
        export AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''
        export S3_BUCKET_NAME=''
fi
```

When running the script it goes to the `set` section. But when inspecting through `echo $AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID # => ''`.

I am not sure what is causing the issue. **I will be interested in...**

1. A fix for this...
2. A way to extract and add `heroku config` variables in the the env in an easier way.

Comment: Are you expecting those variables to survive after the script finishes running?  If so, you need to source the script, not execute it.

Comment: What @John1024 and rici are saying, is that you need to type `source yourscript` rather than `./yourscript`

Comment: Oh I think I get it, I think sh `script.sh` fires a new process or some thing like that may be. Answer another question I was puzzled for a week in getting PHP environment variables as I exported in a shell. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `source` the script, not run it as a child. If you run the script directly, its environment disappears when it ends. Sourcing the script causes it to be executed in the current environment. `help source` for more information.

Example:

```
$ VAR=old_value

$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
export VAR=new_value

$ ./script.sh
$ echo $VAR
old_value

$ source script.sh
$ echo $VAR
new_value
```

Scripts executed with `source` don't need to be executable nor do they need the "shebang" line (`#!/bin/bash`) because they are *not* run as separate processes. In fact, it is probably a good idea to not make them executable in order to avoid them being run as commands, since that won't work as expected.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was completely clueless. Makes perfect sense and worked.